# Get warning when running karma tests in webpack

Tags: unit-testing, webpack, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I have placed my webpack entry for tests under src/. Then inside the entry I have the following to find and run all *.spec.js files inside src directory:

```
var testsContext = require.context('.', true, /.+\.spec\.js?$/);
testsContext.keys().forEach(testsContext);
```

When I run npm test, it runs all my tests successfully, however it keeps giving me this annoying warning:

```
WARNING in ./src .+\.spec\.js?$
Module not found: Error: a dependency to an entry point is not allowed
@ ./src .+\.spec\.js?$
```

Anyone else faced the same issue?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what the warning was. The karma entry itself had spec.js suffix in it. That's why the glob function was finding the file itself, too.